# Having trouble showing and hiding radar layer on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to toggle this google maps radar layer to show and hide whenever I click the associated button. Any help would be appreciated!

Basically, I want this function to toggle on and off whenever I click my "radar" button.

### Javascript:

```
function animateRadar(overlayMapTypes) {
index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;

window.setInterval(function(){

    map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.00);

    index--;
    if(index < 0){
        index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;
    }
    map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.60);
}, 400);
```

}

```
function wx(){
        animateRadar();
       }


$("#wxxx").click(function(){
        $("#weather").toggleClass("active");
            wx();

   });
```

### HTML:

```
<li id ="wxxx"class='radar'>
        <ul id="weather"></ul>
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngkq8dja/3/)

I'm pretty new to jsfiddle, so I'm not too sure how to display images properly. Here's an image of the site as well:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvyK.jpg

Comment: is the contents of the file **markerwithlabel.js** what is inserted into the javascript section of your fiddle? ... not to be too harsh, but this is quite a terrible fiddle sample. you have relative pathed script and link resources in your html section.. the html section represent the innerHtml of the body tag.. which you also have in the html section... it would have warned you to exclude it.. except you have " < " as the first line... a typo I'm sure.. I'm going to try to clean this up a bit... I'll get to ya

Comment: I know, I'm really new to fiddle. The markerwithlabel is the marker for each squad. It's nothing relevant to the actual site it's self right now. I'm going to implement it in later on. 

I appreciate you helping out!

Comment: well.. using jsfiddle aside; your markup and javascript has quite a few errors. I'm not sure if you're aware, but if you open your developer tools in your browser.. there is a console that will indicate (log) when you have syntax errors.. a frequent js error I'm seeing here is having a comma "," at the end of json declarations. `{"id" : 0, "name" : "John Doe",}` will throw an error because of the last comma.. there is also a couple of missing semi-colons ";"... I'm going to remove reference to the **markerwithlabel.js** (link and markup) if it's outside the scope of your issue.

Comment: alrighty.. I cleaned it up.. removed reference to a bit of the background images.. the problem is; however, I don't see it loading the map into the canvas... you had a script reference to **function.js** .. what does that script do?

Comment: Thanks! For some reason jsfiddle won't load the map. I'm not sure why. The functions.js is essentially all of my javascript that's displayed in the javascript template on fiddle. Again, I forgot to take the references out. Any idea on how to show/hide the radar overlay? I've tried the jquery method, but that will just hide the icon.

Comment: How do I view your edit?

Comment: I updated again, this one works.. jquery ui lost it's reference, I had to add it as an external resource.. so now your code sample should be easy to address.

Comment: Looks good! I can't thank you enough for taking the time to tidy it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so yeah.. the answer is actually fairly easy to address without reviewing the output of your sample code on jsfiddle

`window.setInterval(<function>,<value>)` returns a handle, otherwise known as a timerId.

to clear the interval timer, you use `window.clearInterval(timerId)`.. to hide the radar, you iterate over `overlayMapTypes` and set `opacity` to `0`

```
var timerId = -1;

function animateRadar(overlayMapTypes) {
    index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;

    if (timerId >= 0) {
        //stop timer
        window.clearInterval(timerId);
        timerId = -1;        

        //hide overlayMayTypes
        for (var i = 0, max = map.overlayMapTypes.length; i < max; i++) 
        {
            map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(i).setOpacity(0.00);
        }

        return;
    }

    timerId = window.setInterval(function () {


        map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.00);

        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;
        }
        map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.60);
    }, 400);
}
```

---

### For completeness...

I'm going to bring the code sample into this answer (wish I could hide the styling for this, but that isn't in the stacksnippet feature .... yet)

```js
var mapCreated = false;

var mapPoints = new Array();
var names = new Array();
var times = new Array();
var colors = new Array();
initialCenterFocused = false;
var map;
var imageArray = [];
var kmzLayer;
var bounds;
var mapOptions;
var markers = [];
var lines = [];
var fartherTimeThresholdMillis = 36000000;
var nearerTimeThresholdMillis = 0;
var now = new Date();
var endTimeCutOff = now.getTime() - fartherTimeThresholdMillis;
var startTimeCutOff = now.getTime() - nearerTimeThresholdMillis;
var timer;
var playTimer;
var isPlaying = false;
var radar = false;
var index;




function eraseAllMarkersAndLines() {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        lines[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    lines = [];
}

function fetchNewest() {
    console.log("fetching newest");
    nearerTimeThresholdMillis = parseInt(jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 0)) * 60000;
    fartherTimeThresholdMillis = parseInt(jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 1)) * 60000;

    now = new Date();
    endTimeCutOff = now.getTime() - fartherTimeThresholdMillis;
    startTimeCutOff = now.getTime() - nearerTimeThresholdMillis;

    mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.730362, -85.792725));
    names.push("Alpha");
    times.push("1425059747829");
    colors.push("Red");

    mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.73041, -85.79264));
    names.push("Delta");
    times.push("1425059172108");
    colors.push("Blue");

    mapPoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(33.72476, -85.788185));
    names.push("Golf");
    times.push("1425050587395");
    colors.push("Green");

    console.log(names);

    /**
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "fetchNewest14.jsp",
                    data: "endTimeCutOff=" + endTimeCutOff + "&startTimeCutOff=" + startTimeCutOff,
                    dataType: "script",
                    scriptCharset: "utf-8",
                    success: function(data){
                        //console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        //console.log("ERROR, DAVE" + error);
                    }
                })
                .done(function() {
                    if (!mapCreated) {
                        mapCreated = true;          
                        createMap();
                    }
                    
                    updateMap();
                    //console.log(mapPoints);
                });
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout('fetchNewest()', 10000);
                **/
} // end of fetchNewest


function createMap() {
    mapOptions = {
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        zoom: 10,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: mapPoints[0] //{ lat: 33.8137100, lng: 85.7613500}        
    };
    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    
    //function drawWeather(){

    //Load Images and add them to imageArray
    tileNEX = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD',
        isPng: true
    });

    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX);

    tileNEX5 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m05m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD5',
        isPng: true
    });
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX5);

    tileNEX10 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m10m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD10',
        isPng: true,
        optimized: false
    });
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX10);

    tileNEX15 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m15m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD15',
        isPng: true
    });
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX15);

    tileNEX20 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m20m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD20',
        isPng: true
    });
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX20);

    tileNEX25 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m25m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD25',
        isPng: true
    });
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX25);

    tileNEX30 = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (tile, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913-m30m/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y + ".png?" + (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
        opacity: 0.00,
        name: 'NEXRAD30',
        isPng: true
    });
    
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(tileNEX30);
}


var timerId = -1;

function animateRadar(overlayMapTypes) {
    index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;

    if (timerId >= 0) {
        window.clearInterval(timerId);
        timerId = -1;        
        for (var i = 0, max = map.overlayMapTypes.length; i < max; i++) 
        {
            map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(i).setOpacity(0.00);
        }
        return;
    }
    
    timerId = window.setInterval(function () {


        map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.00);

        index--;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = map.overlayMapTypes.getLength() - 1;
        }
        map.overlayMapTypes.getAt(index).setOpacity(0.60);
    }, 400);
}
//}          





function createMarkers() {

}

function updateMap() {
    eraseAllMarkersAndLines();

    //console.log("updating map");
    var markerOpacity = 1.0;
    var zIndex = 10;

    for (var i = 0; i < mapPoints.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && names[i] === names[i - 1]) {

            // this point should be connected to the previous point, so draw a line
            if (markerOpacity > 0) { // only add it if it's not totally transparent
                var lineCoords = [mapPoints[i - 1], mapPoints[i]];
                var lineToDraw = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: lineCoords,
                    map: map,
                    strokeColor: '#000000',
                    strokeOpacity: markerOpacity,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });
                lines.push(lineToDraw);
            }
            // also, fade the marker's opacity a bit, and set it back in layers
            markerOpacity = Math.max(markerOpacity - .1, 0);
            zIndex -= 1;
        } else { // it's a new name
            markerOpacity = 1.0;
            zIndex = 10;
        }

        if (markerOpacity > 0) { // add the marker
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: mapPoints[i],
                map: map,
                labelContent: names[i],
                labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 11),
                labelClass: "labels",
                labelStyle: {
                    opacity: markerOpacity
                },
                zIndex: zIndex,
                labelZIndex: zIndex,
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    strokeColor: "black",
                    fillColor: colors[i],
                    fillOpacity: markerOpacity,
                    strokeOpacity: markerOpacity,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    scale: 15
                },
                InfoWindowShown: true,
                title: String(zIndex)
            });

            // set label text color based on squad color
            var lightColors = new Array("yellow", "pink");
            if (lightColors.indexOf(colors[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) { // set labels to black text
                marker.labelStyle.color = "black";
            } else {
                marker.labelStyle.color = "white";
            }
            // shorten squad names
            var squadNames = {
                alpha: "A",
                bravo: "B",
                charlie: "C",
                delta: "D",
                echo: "E",
                foxtrot: "F",
                golf: "G"
            };
            marker.labelContent = squadNames[marker.labelContent.toLowerCase()];


            markers.push(marker);
            bounds.extend(mapPoints[i]);
        } // end of adding marker
    }
    if (!initialCenterFocused) {
        initialCenterFocused = true;
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    console.log(names);
} // end of updateMap



function moveForward() {
    console.log("moving forward");
    jQuery("#timeslider").slider('values', 1, jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 1) - .5);
    jQuery("#amount").val(jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 0) + " - " + jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 1));
    fetchNewest();

    playTimer = setTimeout('moveForward()', 3000);
}


function setupInterface() {
    // set up the slider
    jQuery("#timeslider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 600,
        step: 0.1,
        values: [0, 300],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            jQuery("#amount").val("" + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    jQuery("#amount").val(jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 0) + " - " + jQuery("#timeslider").slider("values", 1));
    jQuery("#timeslider").on("slidestop", function (event, ui) {
        fetchNewest();
    });

    // set up button
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#myButton").click(function (event) {
            if (!isPlaying) {
                isPlaying = true;
                jQuery("#myButton").prop("value", "Pause");
                clearTimeout(timer);
                moveForward();
            } else {
                isPlaying = false;
                jQuery("#myButton").prop("value", "Play");
                clearTimeout(playTimer);
            }
        });
    });
} // end of setupInterface


function initialize() {
    setupInterface();
    fetchNewest();
    createMap();


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function wx() {
    animateRadar();
}



$("#wxxx").click(function () {
    $("#weather").toggleClass("active");
    wx();

});







/*Checks to see if check boxes were clicked and displays output to console*/
function checkBoxValues(form) {
    var values = [];
    var squads = form.squads;

    /*iterate through check boxes*/
    for (var i in form.squads) {
        if (squads[i].checked) {
            values.push(squads[i].value);
        }
    }
    /*log values to console*/
    alert("Squads: " + values.join(', '));
    return values;
}

initialize();
//***On click open Squads****
```

```css
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
 #cssmenu {
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
#cssmenu ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
    float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    line-height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 599;
    cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 598;
    width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
}
/* Custom Stuff */
 #cssmenu span, #cssmenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li {
    width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li {
    background: #dddddd url(data:image/png;
    base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAJCAMAAAA8eE0hAAAAUVBMVEX////MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNzc3l5eXg4ODZ2dnMzMzi4uLS0tLe3t7Q0NDV1dXj4+PW1tbk5OTc3NzPz8/R0dH0Zv5RAAAAC3RSTlMAM2YekAmlPHuEAwArv7wAAAA/SURBVHheY2Dl5mdigABGKV5BNnYok4dHQpKFGcrkEefj5gAzQUBABM7kFYQyRcX4mUBMkEpOLrA2IWGwfgYAn0UDZszv8IwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #e5e5e5), color-stop(1, #dddddd));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #dddddd);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #dddddd);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #dddddd);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #dddddd);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e5e5e5, #dddddd);
}
#cssmenu li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
#cssmenu a {
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 160%;
    padding: 11px 28px 11px 28px;
    width: 144px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
    background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a {
    color: #AE0001;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li ul li {
    background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #b7b7b7;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:after, #cssmenu .has-sub > ul > .has-sub:hover:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 78%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    background-image: url(data:image/png;
    base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAJCAMAAAA8eE0hAAAAUVBMVEX////MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNzc3l5eXg4ODZ2dnMzMzi4uLS0tLe3t7Q0NDV1dXj4+PW1tbk5OTc3NzPz8/R0dH0Zv5RAAAAC3RSTlMAM2YekAmlPHuEAwArv7wAAAA/SURBVHheY2Dl5mdigABGKV5BNnYok4dHQpKFGcrkEefj5gAzQUBABM7kFYQyRcX4mUBMkEpOLrA2IWGwfgYAn0UDZszv8IwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub > ul > .has-sub:after, #cssmenu .has-sub:hover:after {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;
    base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAJCAMAAAA8eE0hAAAAUVBMVEX////d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3d3e3t729vbx8fHq6urd3d3z8/Pj4+Pv7+/h4eHm5ub09PTn5+f19fXt7e3g4ODi4uLUsVdlAAAAC3RSTlMAM2YekAmlPHuEAwArv7wAAAA/SURBVHheY2Dl5mdigABGKV5BNnYok4dHQpKFGcrkEefj5gAzQUBABM7kFYQyRcX4mUBMkEpOLrA2IWGwfgYAn0UDZszv8IwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.button {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0.1em outset whitesmoke;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.radar {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background: whitesmoke url("images/radar.png") 0 0;
    border:0.1em outset whitesmoke;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#timeslider {
    height:1%;
    width:30%;
    position: absolute;
    top:95%;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#slideTime {
    height:1%;
    width:30%;
    position: absolute;
    top:93%;
    left:0;
    display:block;
    z-index:100;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#map-canvas {
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 5px;border:0.1em outset #A0A0A0;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color:white;
}

body {background-color:whitesmoke;padding:1em;display:block;}

.labels {
    color: black;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#amount[readonly] {
    border:0;
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity:3;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#weather {
    display:none;
}

#weather.active {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    border:0.1em solid black;
    height:2em;
    width:2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li id="myButton" class='button'>Button</li>
        <li id="wxxx" class='radar'>Radar
            <ul id="weather"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="timeslider"></div>
<div id="slideTime">
    <label for="amount">Minutes ago:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly />
</div>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: IT WORKS! I never would have thought to create a timer. I thought it would have been more CSS or jquery based. 

Thanks a bunch! I'd buy you a beer if I could.

Comment: @user3543426, I added a CSSStyleDeclaration for **#weather.active** in this stacksnippet sample.. I don't know whether you intended to actually display that element, but it's worth some consideration to add an indicator...