# Having trouble with $.get in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, syntax, api-design

I'm a newbie to JavaScript.  Now that I got that out of the way, I'm experiencing a very weird error.  I'm building an application to show the current weather at your location, and to do this I needed to make an API call for the weather data.  I got the weather data from [here](http://openweathermap.org/current) and at first, my code was working and getting the local weather (for a given latitude and longitude).  However, I was making edits to my code to add functionality and my code suddenly stopped working.  I tried to fix it but I'm flummoxed, I have no idea what I broke.  I'm hoping you guys can help!!

Here is my code for reference:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(lat);
        $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=00d71b03a3c50910d8f4f0ea51703bb5', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(lat == 300 || long == 300) {
                alert("Enable your location to see how the weather is");
            } else {
                $("#location").text(data.name);
                var weather = data.weather[0].description;
                $("#weather").text(weather);
                temp = Math.round((data.main.temp - 273.15) * 10) / 10.0;
                $("#temperature").text(temp + "\u00B0 C");
                var icon = data.weather[0].icon;
                $("#picture").attr("src", "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
            } 
        });
    });
};
```

I put a `console.log(data)` below the API call to see what is happening, but it doesn't output anything.  Very confused, please help!

Comment: the issue is somewhere else if `$.get` isn't returning anything.. `$.get` should return the result of the request.. the data here should be `data.data` since you're call the result `data`.

Comment: Your code works on my end. I'm running it local in a document.ready event with jquery. It does not work however here on a stack snippet. What environment are you running in?

Comment: yeah.. I was wrong..haven't worked with just jQuery in awhile.. used to IHttpService on angular.. seems it does automatically return result.data there..

Comment: still, you should use web tools (usually `F12`) and look at your network tab to see if the xhr call is being made to that endpoint.

also, do you have a jquery plugin affecting `$.get` at all?

Comment: The problem might be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) related. Check your network tab in your dev tools, you can find out what causes `data` be empty.

Comment: Depending on browser if your site is "https" and you are requesting the weather data on "http" then it will block it as "mixed mode content".  I know on Chrome at least you could run into this issue.  Just a shot in the dark

Comment: @BrettCaswell I looked at the XHR call tab and it had no information on it.  And I'm not entirely sure what you mean by having a jquery plugin affecting $.get.  I don't think so though...

Comment: @ThisClark At first I was coding this on CodePen, and at what point it was working and then it suddenly just stopped.  Then out of frustration/desperation I switched to Sublime 3.  Is it actually getting the weather data for you??

Comment: @choz I checked my network tab, but I'm not entirely sure how to interpret the information correctly to find out what data is empty.  Any tips on what to look for?

Comment: You know the API has limits ... e.g., `Do not send requests more then 1 time per 10 minutes from one device/one API key`

Comment: @lww515 here is a solution that might take your project into a different direction. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28911718/1366179

Comment: @lww515 Yes, it definitely worked using your code. The problem I run into is using other environments like codepen, jsfiddle, and stack snippets. Also, I can't run it from a site on https (like Github Pages or HyperDev) because of security mixed modes as the api is on plaintext http.

Comment: @JaromandaX I do know the API has limits.  The website I'm making the API call to said I can make no more than 60 requests per minute on a free subscription, I believe.

Comment: the `Do not send requests more then 1 time per 10 minutes from one device/one API key` is a quote from the site you are using ... 60 per minute is 600 times more than 1 per 10 minutes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run this code in firefox and get json data from api.openweathermap.org

Check if your browser support navigator.geolocation and permit share your location.

---

the following snippet overrides `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and invokes the inner `fn` with `.bind` to force it fire.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var appId = "00d71b03a3c50910d8f4f0ea51703bb5";
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        // TODO: remove this for production. DEMO/DEBUG usage
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(fn)  {
            fn.bind(this, { coords : { latitude : 51.507351, longitude : -0.127758 }})();
        }; 

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            try {
          
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                long = position.coords.longitude;
    
                $.get('//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=' + appId, function(data) {
                    console.log("data := %o", data);        
    
                    if(lat == 300 || long == 300) {
                        alert("Enable your location to see how the weather is");
                    } else {
                        $("#location").text(data.name);
                        var weather = data.weather[0].description;
                        $("#weather").text(weather);
                        temp = Math.round((data.main.temp - 273.15) * 10) / 10.0;
                        $("#temperature").text(temp + "\u00B0 C");
                        var icon = data.weather[0].icon;
                        $("#picture").attr("src", "//openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
                    } 
                });
            } catch(error) {
                console.log("err := %o", error);
            }            
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="location">Location</label><span id="location"></span>
<label for="weather">Weather</label><div id="weather"></div>
<label for="temperature">Temperature (F)</label><span id="temperature"></span>
<img id="picture" src="" width="200px" height="200px" />
```

Comment: I made sure my location was turned on and that the websites I used supported navigator.geolocation, and that code snippet did not work :(( Thank you for taking the time to try and help me though!

Comment: thus, the scope of your issue is either with `getCurrentPosition` (reads from sensors btw.. which you can mock in web tools > more tools > sensors) or something is intercepting your calls (could be browser extension issue)

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thank you, I really appreciate the help.  I'll try these in the morning and see if it works :)

Comment: @lww515 having said that, your issue is most likely in regards to the sensor consideration.. follow the steps I mentioned to override geolocation sensor in your web tools / dev tools ..

Comment: also note the removal of `http:` in the url for the `$.get` call and `img.src` assignment.. 

by removing the protocol in the url, it will use the current request's protocol..

Comment: @BrettCaswell I tried out your code, but for some reason it's still not working for me.  I have no idea why it still can't make the call to the API :-(